# subscribing on scheduler.io() is not working

Tags: android, rx-java2

My viewmodel calls the repository methods to fetch some data from room database and also from network.

```
     class Repository @Inject constructor(
        private val remoteDatasource: IRemoteSource,
        private val localDatasource: ILocalSource,
        private val subscriberScheduler: Scheduler,
        private val observerScheduler: Scheduler
    ) : IRepository {
    //this method fetches data from room
        override fun getData(): Flowable<Boolean> {
            return localDatasource.shouldFetchRemote().subscribeOn(subscriberScheduler)
           .observeOn(observerScheduler)
        }
// makes api call
override fun getRemoteData(): Flowable<Data> {
            return remoteDatasource.getData().subscribeOn(subscriberScheduler)
           .observeOn(observerScheduler)
        }
```

subscriberScheduler is Schedulers.io() and observer scheduler is AndroidSchedulers.mainThread().
I get exception when I do query from room, saying that the opertion is in main thread. 
Also when I get data from remote source, I check the thread, it is main thread, but this no exception like network call on main thread.

Here is my localsource class which uses room:

```
class Localsource  constructor(private val dataDao: DataDao):ILocalSource {

    override fun shouldFetchRemote(): Flowable<Boolean> {
        if (Looper.getMainLooper().thread == Thread.currentThread()) {
            Log.v("thread","main thread")
            //this log prints
        }
       //exception thrown here
       return Flowable.just(dataDao.isDataPresent() != 0)
}
```

Here is class for RemoteSource

```
@OpenForTesting
class Remotesource @Inject constructor():IRemoteSource{



    override fun getData(): Flowable<Data> {
        if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
            Log.v("thread","main thread") 
    //this log prints but no exception is thrown like network call on main thread.

        }
        return service.getData().flatMap { Flowable.just(it.data) }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions about what happens where are wrong. That is an issue.

Lets look at `shouldFetchRemote()` method.

```
//This part will always be on the main thread because it is run on it.
//Schedulers applied only for the created reactive 
//stream(Flowable, Observable, Single etc.) but not for the rest of the code in the method.
        if (Looper.getMainLooper().thread == Thread.currentThread()) {
            Log.v("thread","main thread")
            //this log prints
        }
       //exception thrown here
//Yes it is correct that exception is thrown in this line 
//because you do reach for the database on the main thread here.

//It is because Flowable.just() creates stream out of the independent data 
//that does not know anything about scheduler here.

// dataDao.isDataPresent() - is run on the main thread 
//because it is not yet part of the reactive stream - only its result is!!!! 
//That is crucial
       return Flowable.just(dataDao.isDataPresent() != 0)
```

In order to include the function into a stream you need to take another approach. Room has an ability to return Flowables directly and store booleans. This way you can use it like this

In DAO

```
@Query(...)
Boolean isDataPresent(): Flowable<Boolean>
```

In your local source

```
 override fun shouldFetchRemote(): Flowable<Boolean> = dataDao.isDataPresent()
```

This way it will work as expected because now the whole function is the part of reactive stream and will react to schedulers.

The same with remote sourse. `Retrofit` can return Observables or Flowables out of the box

```
interface Service{

@GET("data")
fun getData(): Flowable<Data>

}

// and the repo will be

val service = retrofit.create(Service::class.java)

override fun getData(): Flowable<Data> = service.getData()
```

This way everything will work as expected because now it is the part of a stream.

If you want to use plan data from Room or Retrofit - you can do it either. The only thing is Flowable.just() won't work.

For example for your local source you will need to do something like

```
//DAO
@Query(...)
Boolean isDataPresent(): Boolean


 override fun shouldFetchRemote(): Flowable<Boolean> = Flowable.create<Boolean>(
                    { emitter ->
                      emitter.onNext(dataDao.isDataPresent())
                      emitter.onComplete() //This is crucial because without onComplete the emitter won't emit anything
//There is also emitter.onError(throwable: Throwable) to handle errors

 }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST).toObservable() // there are different Backpressure Strategies
```

There are similar factories for Obserwable and other reactive stream.

And generally I would recommend you to read the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/).

Comment: the remote service is returning me the whole response and I have to flatmap it to return the data, so its like override fun getData(): Flowable<Data> {
        
        }
      //service.getData returns Flowable<Response>
        return service.getData().flatMap { Flowable.just(it.data) }
    }
    }

Comment: Nope. You can use map{it.data} - if the service returns Flowable, map() method does not alter it. flatMap() is used only to return reactive stream sources - you don't need it here - you have just the response already wrapped into a reactive stream. You don't need one more wrapping.